# Jquery append function only works on initial ajax request, requires page refresh to repopulate another div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am making an AJAX request to get an JSON array, upon success another AJAX request is performed and the contents are populated to the div of a bootstrap modal via jquery append function. Everything works correctly for the first selection, however, once I close the modal and attempt another entry the append function no longer populates the div. I attempted to empty the contents of the div and also tried the clone function but no matter what the contents are not repopulated until a page refresh. I tried logging to the console and the data is correct and repopulated with each click. Sorry if my code is terrible, still learning. Below is the code I am using.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
     function makeModal({first_name, last_name, id}) {
                return `
                <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">${first_name} ${last_name}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                <p>${last_name}</p>
                <p>${id}</p>
                <p id="job_history"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>`;
          }

          //onclick event
      $(document).on('click', '.applicant_detail', function(e) {

        var id = $(this).data('id');
        //$('#job_history').empty();
         $('#myModal').modal('dispose');

        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/admin/get_applicant",
              dataType: 'json',
              data: {id:id},
              success: function(data) {

                    var count = Object.keys(data).length;

                    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                          var m1 = $(makeModal({last_name:element.last_name, first_name:element.first_name, id:element.id})); 
                          document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', m1);
                          m1.modal('show');
                    });
                          $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/admin/get_job_history",
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data: {application_id:id},
                                success: function(data) {

                                     var count = Object.keys(data).length;

                                     $.each(data, function(index, element) {

                                      $('#job_history').append("Job Title: " + element.job_title + '<br>').clone();

                                      console.log('Job Title: ' + element.job_title);
                                });
                               },   
                         });    
                    },
              });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. I needed to destroy the modal created via my makeModal function. So I removed the div with each click event. Not sure if this is the best way but it works.

```
$('#myModal').remove();  //added this below the click event
```